# How to refresh existing tables in Google Big Query with a schedule query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new in Google Big Query and I have created a query that is union different tables and I have set a schedule query to run on demand with the option to overwriting the destination table. However, when running the schedule query the destination table refreshes by duplicating the data. But I just want  want to refresh the table and making sure that the amount of data is the same as the sourced tables.

Someone can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off "SHOW PREVIEW FEATURES". Then there should be an option to overwrite destination table instead of appending to it during sheduled query creation.

[image]

Comment: HI, I was using overwrite table option on  schedule query and it was duplicating the data. And I have been hiding the "SHOW PREVIEW FEATURES" option

Comment: Maybe Is this because I have not been specifying which column  to select instead using Select * ? and The schedule query was crashing?